# Setting Up Angular JS MVC Demo in Visual Studio (Empty Asp.NET project)

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

A real basic question here. I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial to learn Angular JS:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKkUN-mJtPQ&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWKHkcL7RJmmXyxkuFB3KSl

At around 4:10 he opens up Visual Studio and his solution explorer looks like this:

[image]

My question is simply what do I need to do in Visual Studio to replicate this solution? I already tried going to file, new, project, and selected "Blank Solution" under "Other Project Types" > "Visual Studio Solutions",

[image]

and after doing this my solution explorer looks like this:

[image]

So I have the top part, "Solution 'Demo' (1 project)", but not the green globe icon next to "Demo", and"Properties", "References", etc. So then I went ahead and clicked on "Solution 'Demo' (1 project)" and hit add > new project, and selected "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)", then selected "Empty", and it gave me this:

[image]

Is this correct? The icon next to "Demo" is blue, not green. And there are a bunch of other folders and files that I will need to delete / remake. Just want to make sure I've selected the correct options to follow along with the tutorial. This is Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You need to make an empty ASP.NET project, not an empty solution.

Comment: I see. Got it working now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to create an empty ASP.NET project, simply by going to File --> New --> Project, and under Templates --> Visual C#, selecting ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) --> OK.

[image]